# What is the earliest evidence of vocation and birth based social stratification?

Tags: social-history, ancient-india

The caste system in India as practiced today has several layers of complexities, mostly undesirable ones. But it's a reality. 
Now, it's commonly accepted that the Indus Valley civilization involved people from parts of present day Europe. 
I am trying to understand if this practice has origins elsewhere or if the caste system has it's origins in this sub-continent itself.

An alternative way to put my query is: 
What, if any, is the earliest evidence of a practice similar to the caste system in the world?

Comment: "the Indus Valley civilization involved people from parts of present day Europe" - first time I've heard this. Can you provide your sources?

Comment: I am referring to the 'Aryans' when I say, 'people from present day Europe'. I guess, it's inaccurate term, let me see if I can replace it with a better one. 

Link of settlers of Indus valley civilization with the migrants from Central Asia has been established in multiple research. 
Here is one: 
[link] (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16096211 )

Comment: You are more amateur than me. The Indus valley Civilization was the pre-Aryan civilization of Northern India. It belonged to a round headed people related to the Sumerians. the aryans had a rigid hereditary caste system. I'm not sure of any earlier examples but it probably predates them.

Comment: As rediculous as this guys connections seem; its actually being pushed by the mainstream, ie indigenous Aryans.

Comment: @JohnDee  
You are right about me, the amateur part. No contest there. :-)  
I was deliberately attempting to avoid using the term 'Aryan' to prevent any biased (pro-anti migration groups) reactions. 

Can you point me towards more details on the Sumerian links of Indus Valley Civilization?

Comment: Not sure but I would search for "round headed Sumerian Dravidian". it's the idea that they spread slowly from Africa along the coastline. I'm also not positive that the Aryans brought their caste structure from Aryana because the Brahman religion was a development that occured in India. I think they did bring it though.

Comment: My last two sentences echoes you own question, if you didn't notice.

Comment: @JohnDee "the aryans had a rigid hereditary caste system" - but the first mentions of caste system (varnas) are dated to 1500-1300 BC, and Indus Valley civilisation collapsed (possibly due to Aryan invasion) long before that (all of Late Harappan cities seem to be abandoned by 1700 BC). How do we know if Aryans had caste system at the moment of the invasion?

Comment: @DanilaSmirnov 
... "How do we know if Aryans had caste system at the moment of the invasion? "

This presumes an invasion.

Comment: It would have been whatever the Indo-Aryans had in Aryana Vaeja. Why is it thought to be theirs? The common idea is that Aryans imposed themselves on the Indus people through a hereditary hierarchy (priests, warriors...). Therefore, its thought that the system was definitively theirs. Maybe it was created as a result of the aryan-Indus collision, in order to keep themselves distinct.

Comment: Archaeologists have suggested evidence of caste system (segregated communities) during Indus Valley Civilization. So, either the Aryans were not the only ones with a caste system or there is a common source somewhere. 

But my original concern still remains. 
What is the earliest evidence of such system? Whether Aryans or not. Invasion or not.

Comment: The invasion is not a presumption.

Comment: ... "The invasion is not a presumption."  :-) Ok. Maybe in another thread, we will come to it in detail. To the extent I have heard and read, it was a mix of invasion and migration over a period of time. 
For now, I am trying to get the earliest evidences of a caste system in a society.

Comment: Invasion or migration, in the scope of this question the point is - we know they got to Indus Valley, but we don't know if at that point they had a caste-based society that we couldn't call "Indian".

On the segregated communities - cities being divided into walled communities does not necessarily imply caste system. It might be segregation by wealth, which was omnipresent (and some might argue that it still is).

Comment: @KeenPine - Isn't this a basic question on complex societies couched in another form (_stratification_)? Any specialist books on this topic will address the question. On Indus Valley Civilisation, I believe you will find your answer in archaeologist of [Altin Tepe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altyndepe), Vadim Masson - they had 4 levels of stratification.

Comment: @J Asia Social stratification is basic, hereditary castes are not. If what you said about Altyn Depe has substance than its a big deal.